# Creating mock objects with a private build function fails

Tags: phpunit, mockery

I'm using PHPUnit for auto-testing my app and it works fine so far. But now I've the followijng problem:
I have some tests - let's say 50. In all these tests I want to use mockerys and because I need the same objects everytime, I tried to refactor the creation of the mock objects to a private function and call it from within every test. But I can't get it to work.
My private build function looks like this:

```
private function createMyMocks() {
  $person = $this->getMockBuilder(Person::class)->getMock();

  $car = $this->getMockBuilder(Car::class)
    ->setMethods(['getDriver'])
    ->getMock();
  $car->expects($this->once())
    ->setMethod('getDriver')
    ->willReturn($person);

  return $car;
}
```

Comment: Are all these tests in the same file or you have different files? And can you please at least include 1 test that calls this function?

Comment: You've tagged this question with [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/), but it seems you are using PHPUnit's mocking functionality. Which one are you planning on using? With Mockery, you would do something like this: `$car = \Mockery::mock(Car::class); $car->shouldReceive('getDriver')->andReturn($person);`.